# Package iPad webapp to a downloadable iPad app and submit to App Store

Tags: ios, ipad, web-applications

We are creating a web application for iPad, which doesn't have offline features for now. We are thinking if we need to create a downloadable iPad app and submit to App Store. The web application could run in some kind of embedded browser so that it looks like a native app.

Here are my questions regarding this:

1. Is it good/necessary to create a downloadable iPad app to let user have same experience to native apps on iPad?
2. Does Apple allow this kind of app to submit to App Store?
3. Are there any best practices for installation of iPad web applications? Is the way of typing URL in iPad safari (or homescreen icon) acceptable/preferred for most users?
4. How did you manage the installation process for your iPad web applications?

Thanks,
J

Comment: There are apps like this, for example from Google

Comment: You definitely need to handle the offline case, at least by showing some dignified message telling them they need internet connection! and it would cost them data fees just opening your app

Comment: Apple's [Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality) specifically say: *"Apps that are not very useful, **are simply web sites bundled as apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value **may be rejected**"*

Comment: The Kindle Store web app is a nice example.